# Add content to drupalgap drop down

Tags: 7, javascript

I have recently started working with D7. I made a test page and installed drupal gap to run it with mobile-application. I wants to assigned more nodes to the drop down menu under contents, taxonomy and users but I don't know how get this. I have added a screen shot to make it more clear.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the Main Menu section as I see.

You need to made changes "`settings.js`" file present inside **mobile-application\app** folder.

Example:

```
// Main Menu
drupalgap.settings.menus['main_menu'] = {
  options: menu_popup_get_default_options(),
  links: [
    /*
    {
      title:'Content',
      path:'node',
      options:{
        attributes: {
          'data-icon': 'star',
          'class': 'ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      title:'Taxonomy',
      path:'taxonomy/vocabularies',
      options:{
        attributes:{
          'data-icon':'grid'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      title:'Users',
      path:'user-listing',
      options:{
        attributes:{
          'data-icon':'info'
        }
      }
    }
    */
    {
      title:'Home',
      path:'home',
      options:{
        attributes: {
          'data-icon': 'home',
          'class': 'ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      title:'Services',
      path:'websolution',
      options:{
        attributes:{
          'data-icon':'star'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      title:'Our Work',
      path:'ourwork',
      options:{
        attributes:{
          'data-icon':'star'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      title:'About Us',
      path:'articles',
      options:{
        attributes:{
          'data-icon':'star'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      title:'Testimonials',
      path:'testimonial',
      options:{
        attributes:{
          'data-icon':'star'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      title:'Contact',
      path:'node/58',
      options:{
        attributes:{
          'data-icon':'action'
        }
      }
    }

  ]
};
```

You will get details http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Menus

Comment: Thank you, I looked into it a bit more and tried that out but still doesn't show. Is there any steps prior to that?